# Parallels PLESK 12.0.18 - PHP exec() disabled

Tags: php, exec, plesk

I've been trying to `exec()` an exe which calls `wkhtmltopdf` to produce a PDF and then push it to the browser.

However, `exec()` and `system()` and `shell_exec()` seem to be not working under Plesk 12.0.18 on a windows machine, presumably for some crappy security reason.

Does someone know how I can go about enabling this? I know safe mode no longer exists in PHP 5.6 so I am not sure why this isn't working.

Very annoyed. I have root access as this is a dedicated server with 1 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled PLESK and installed Wamp Server.

Problem solved.